# SQL Column title from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables

```
Index | Name | GroupIndex \\table1
1     | A    | 1
2     | A    | 1
3     | A    | 2

Index | GroupName \\table2
1     | G1    
2     | G2
```

I would like my result to be

```
Index | Name | G1 | G2
1     | A    | 2  | 1
```

where I need to display the number of entries of `Name` grouped by `GroupIndex`, but in a column format.

I couldn't find a way to add columns dynamically, from another table. Can you help me out?

Comment: use pivot to convert table rows to columns

Comment: `Select B.Index, A.Name, 1 as G1 , 2 as G2 from (select A.GroupIndex, B.GroupName, B.Index from Table 1 A inner join Table 2 B on A.GroupIndex = B.Index) Pivot (count(A.GroupIndex) for B.Index in (1, 2)) as pvt ORDER by B.Index` see if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table #table1 ([Index] int,Name char(1), GroupIndex int)
create table #table2 ([Index] int,GroupName char(2))

insert into #table1 values
(1,'A',1),
(2,'A',1),
(3,'A',2)

insert into #table2 values
(1,'G1'),
(2,'G2')

--select * from #table1
--select * from #table2

select * from
    (select t1.[GroupIndex] as [Index], t1.Name, t2.[Index] as gi, t2.GroupName 
    from #table1 t1
    inner join #table2 t2 on t2.[Index] = t1.[Index]) as s
PIVOT
    (max(gi) FOR GroupName in (G1,G2)) as pvt
```

---

```
--RESULTS--

Index   Name    G1  G2
1       A       1   2
```

Comment: `GroupName in (G1,G2)` - Is there any way to extend it to n groups?

Comment: Yes @KarthikNishanth  but that involves dynamic SQL. Very doable though.

Answer (score 1):

create a pivot that group your user by name then count their groups using sum function for each group.

```
SELECT
    Sum(case when tbl2.[index]=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end ) AS G1,
    SUM(case when tbl2.[index]=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0  end ) AS G2
 FROM tbl1
join tbl2 on tbl2.[index] = tbl1.GroupIndex group by tbl1.Name
```

[image]